# Какие варианты парсить информацию?

Tags: python, парсер, график

Передо мной стала задача, которую, наверное, я сам не смогу решить. А именно, нужно спарсить информацию.

На сайте hltv org, в профиле команды, есть архивная информация рейтинга этой команды, в виде графика.

[image: график]

При наведении курсора мыши на кривую, появляется плашка с той самой архивной информацией, которую я хочу взять.

[image: архивная информация]

С обычным парсингом у меня проблем нет. Регулярно пользуюсь библиотекой BeautifulSoup. Но здесь все сложнее. Я не понимаю куда "рыть".

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что здесь можно сделать?

Для примера, ссылка на команду Астралис https://www.hltv.org/team/6665/astralis

Comment: Информация из графика хранится в этом блоке `<div class="graph " id="uniqueChartId-1788671870" data-fusionchart-config="{`

Comment: @m0nte-cr1st0, долго смотрел на этот блок, кроме точек оси икс и игрик, ничего такого, за что можно зацепится, не нашел. можешь подробнее описать свои мысли

Comment: там, очевидно, json, который Вам нужно вытащить

Comment: @m0nte-cr1st0, спасибо! получилось)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Информация из графика хранится как `json` в свойстве `data-fusionchart-config` вот этого элемента:

`<div class="graph " id="uniqueChartId-775479281" data-fusionchart-config="{"width":"100%","dataFormat":"json", ... }">`

Нужно сначала вытащить её - и дальше уже с ней работать особого труда не должно составить.

Comment: Это не совсем ответ. В Вашем комментарии к вопросу и то было понятнее. Сделайте более полный ответ, пожалуйста.

Comment: По-моему, ответ очевиден. Автор спросил, куда "рыть" - я сказал, ему помогло.

Comment: Я поправил Ваш ответ сам, чтобы было понятно, что имелось в виду

Comment: @Sergey Nudnov, подскажите пожалуйста, а как Вы определили, что данные, которые отображаются на графике - именно начинаются с этой секции ? Если будет другой сайт и другой график, то есть какой то универсальный способ, как определить ?

Comment: на каждом сайте своя разметка и свои методы реализации. тут всё индивидуально.

Answer (score 1):

Библиотека "requests" вам в помощь. 
Нажмите в браузере F12 и перейдите во вкладку 'Network' и увидите, какой запрос посылает браузер к серверу и что тот на него отвечает.

Comment: К сожалению, там ничего интересного нет

Comment: Поясните, что конкретно Вы хотите извлечь из информации, которая открывается при наведении курсора?

Comment: Позицию в рейтинге и дату